Finding Rational Canonical Form from Rank information
I encountered this example on computing RCF(Rational Canonical Form) in the lecture note and failed to understand some key steps in the solution.
Example: Let $A$ be a $15 \times 15$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and suppose we're given the following information:($c_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, $m_A(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$)

$c_A(x)=(x+1)^5 (x^2+x+1)^5$
$m_A(x) = (x+1)^3 (x^2+x+1)^2$
$\text{rank}(A+I)=13$
$\text{rank}(A^2+A+I)=9$

Find the RCF of $A$.
Solution: Let $V = \mathbb{F}_2^{15}$ and denote the map $v\mapsto Av$ by $A$. Using Primary Decomposition Theorem, we know that $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$, where $V_1 = \ker(A+I)^3$ , $V_2 = \ker(A^2+A+I)^2$, of dimension $5,10$, respectively (using information in $1,2$).
By $2$, the RCF of the restriction map $A_{V_1}$ is either
$$\text{(a) }C(x+1)^3\oplus C(x+1)^2 \text{ or (b)} C(x+1)^3\oplus C(x+1) \oplus C(x+1)$$
By $3$, $\text{rank}(A_{V_1}+I_{V_1}) = 3$, so there're $2$ blocks. Hence case (a) holds.
By $2$, writing $f(x)=x^2+x+1$, the RCF of $A_{V_2}$ is either
$$\text{(c) }C(f^2) \oplus C(f^2) \oplus C(f) \text{ or (d) } C(f^2) \oplus C(f) \oplus C(f) \oplus C(f) $$
By $4$, $\text{rank}(A^2_{V_2}+A_{V_2}+I_{V_2})  = 4$, so $(c)$ holds. Hence t he RCF of $A$ is
$$C(x+1)^3 \oplus C(x+1)^2 \oplus C(f^2) \oplus C(f^2) \oplus C(f)$$
Questions:

How do you deduce the dimension of $V_1,V_2$ from 1,2?
How do you go from $\text{rank}(A_{V_1}+I_{V_1}) = 3$ to deducing that there're two blocks in the RCF of $A_{V_2}$? Same question on using $4$ to choose between $(c),(d)$.

My Attempt:

The dimension of a vector space $V$ is same as the degree of the characteristic polynomial of any linear map $T:V\to V$. $(x+1)^3$ is the minimal polynomial of $A_{V_1}$, and it divides the characteristic polynomial of $A_{V_1}$ which divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$. I managed to show that $c_{A_{V_1}}(x) = (x+1)^5$ and similarily $c_{A_{V_2}}(x)= (x^2 + x +1)^5$. I would like to know if there's a shorter way of noticing this.
I recall that in the case of JCF, the geometric multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to the number of $\lambda$-Jordan blocks present. I tried to find a parallel in RCF but didn't manage to proceed further.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!
